# Angular 4 + zonejs: routing stops working after uncaught error

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, navigation, zonejs

If there is an uncaught error from a component (constructor or ngOnInit) during routing the navigation won't work anymore afterwards.

This happens even if there is an global ErrorHandler and an ErrorHandler for the RouterModule, added an ZoneListener to be sure as well - see app.module.ts

Minimal example here:
https://embed.plnkr.co/L19S3hKWyqgKUIT1EJlI/preview

Make sure to open the console. Once you clicked "Example Component" there are some stacktraces as a result of the forced error in ExampleFormComponent. After that you can't navigate back to "Home".

**How to handle unexpected, uncaught errors to make sure they don't break down the whole app?**

Comment: Check this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2413). Will probably be fixed in the next version

Comment: @PierreDuc I think it won't help. You can set 4.1.1 version in plunker

Comment: @PierreDuc: yurzui is right, even with 4.1.1 the problem remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do some workaround like:

```
let hasRouterError = false;
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private inj: Injector) {}

  handleError(error: any): void {
    console.log('MyErrorHandler: ' + error);

    if(hasRouterError) {
      let router = this.inj.get(Router);
      router.navigated = false;
    }

    //throw error; // it is necessarily otherwise handleError won't be executed during next error
  }
}

export function MyRouterErrorHandler(error: any) {
  console.log('RouterErrorHandler: ' + error);
  hasRouterError = true;
  throw error;
}
```

and we have to use custom `RouteReuseStrategy`:

```
export class PreventErrorRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { return false; }
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle): void {}
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { return false; }
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle|null { return null; }
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    if(hasRouterError) {
      hasRouterError = false;
      return false;
    }
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
  }
}
```

It differs from the `DefaultRouteReuseStrategy` only one this code

```
if(hasRouterError) {
  hasRouterError = false;
  return false;
}
```

don't forget to add it to providers array:

```
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
...
{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: PreventErrorRouteReuseStrategy },
```

You can try it in **[Modified Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/7tSFTI52YxLGCGhcv5lM/)**

Comment: yurzui, I already upvoted but I stumbled upon the input of `shouldReuseRoute`. I know the doc writes them as future, curr but if you put a debugger on that line and navigate from `home` to `about` for example, the `future.routeConfig` becomes `home`. Isn't it reversed?

Comment: @echonax It's strange but you can observe the same behavior with default strategy http://take.ms/DpW8O It doesn't matter `future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig` or `curr.routeConfig === future.routeConfig` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.1/packages/router/src/router.ts#L198-L206

Comment: @yurzui: Thanks a lot - after some struggle we got it working with your workaround! Our routerLinks didn't start with a slash, that produced a new problem :) - if you feel like it take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889889